# Yocto: check final content of MACHINE_FEATURES

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I want to know the exact content of `MACHINE_FEATURES`.
The first thing I tried was:

```
bitbake -e <image> > bitbake.txt
```

inspecting the file I find rows like these:

```
MACHINE_EXTRA_RDEPENDS=""
#
# $MACHINE_EXTRA_RRECOMMENDS [10 operations]
#   _append /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/meta-st/meta-st-stm32mp/conf/machine/include/st-machine-features-stm32mp.inc:54
#     "     ${GPU_IMAGE_INSTALL}          ${OPTEE_IMAGE_INSTALL}        ${ALSA_ADDONS_INSTALL}        ${BLUETOOTH_IMAGE_INSTALL}    "
#   set /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/meta-st/meta-st-stm32mp/conf/machine/include/st-machine-common-stm32mp.inc:38
#     " kernel-modules"
#   _append /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/meta-st/meta-st-stm32mp/conf/machine/include/st-machine-common-stm32mp.inc:52
#     " ${@bb.utils.contains('MACHINE_FEATURES', 'wifi', 'linux-firmware-bcm43430', '', d)} "
#   _append /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/meta-st/meta-st-stm32mp/conf/machine/include/st-machine-common-stm32mp.inc:53
#     " ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES','systemd',' wifi-suspend ','',d)} "
```

The `#` chars mean they are comment? I mean, the `wifi` feature is actually added to `MACHINE_FEATURES`?

How to print out the contents of such a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just go like `bitbake -e <image> | grep "^MACHINE_FEATURES"`. The commented out lines only hold the evaluation as it happens. For the end result, the only thing that matters is the line which states `MACHINE_FEATURES =` right at the beginning.

Comment: I did it without the `^` flag... so I didn't catch the summarize line (the one with the `=`) due to the "noise" of the others!